# Angular) How to set up session while returning jwt

Tags: angular, rxjs

When the controller calls the service, it returns a jwt token. At this time, I tried to use the do function because I wanted to set up a session at the same time, but an error occurred.

How to set up session while returning jwt?

```
loginRequest(form: NgForm) {
        this.isLoading = true;
        const email = form.value.email;
        const password = form.value.password;
        this.auth.login(email, password).subscribe(() => {
            console.log('User is logged in');
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
        });
    }
```

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
        return this.http
            .post<Jwt>(`${BASE_URL.url}/users/login`, {
                email: email,
                password: password,
            })
            do((result) => this.setSession);
                        // Property 'do' does not exist on type 'Observable<Jwt>'
    }

    private setSession(authResult: Jwt) {
        const expiresAt = moment().add(authResult.expiresIn, 'second');

        localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
        localStorage.setItem('expires_at', JSON.stringify(expiresAt.valueOf()));
    }
```

Comment: you need to `.pipe( do(...))` thought i would use tap instead like ProSheta's answer

Answer (score 1):

use tap operator inside pipe

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
        return this.http
            .post<Jwt>(`${BASE_URL.url}/users/login`, {
                email: email,
                password: password,
            }).pipe(tap((result) => this.setSession));
    }

    private setSession(authResult: Jwt) {
        const expiresAt = moment().add(authResult.expiresIn, 'second');

        localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
        localStorage.setItem('expires_at', JSON.stringify(expiresAt.valueOf()));
    }
```